# how multiple processes effect the same Tkinter window in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, process

I am beginner in python and want to know can we run multiple processes on same tkinter window if yes, How ? What will be effects on tkinter windows during multiple processes?

Comment: Is this your homework question ?

Comment: Exercise question.

Answer (score 0):

No, multiple processes cannot share a single window. You can certainly write a program using multiple processes which share data, but only one process can access the tkinter objects.